# What's a good power supply (volts and Amps) to power a USB hub to use with external HDs

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply, raspberry-pi, usb-hub

I'm using a 7 port usb hub found here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-Power-Adapter-Cable-for-PC-Laptop-7-Port-USB-3-0-Hub-On-Off-Switches-/331707642029

The power supply it came with was very weak. It could not power on my external 2TB hard drive so I replaced it with a 5VCD 2.5A adapter of my own. It was able to power the hard drives now. Now the issue is that I connect a second 1TB hard drive on that Hub and things get unstable. It works fine if I connect it directly to my laptop. I'm using a raspberry pie which isn't able to power these hardrive on its own.

Hard drive details: 
2TB seagate backup plus and 1TB WD blue
both are 2.5" in size and 5400rpm.
The 1TB WD drive uses 5VDC and 0.55A. 
I have no idea how much power specs the Seagate one uses.

I think I might need a better power supply to get rid of these issues but I don't know how much volts and amps it needs to be.

Comment: This entirely depends on the voltage and amp requirements of the HDDs themselfs.

Comment: In any case, I'll just need to know how much power a typical usb 2.0 or 3.0 on a laptop supply to connected devices so that I can replace the hub's power supply accordingly. These drives work well on my laptop and they do not power themselves.

Comment: Just for more info, when I connected the 7 port hub to my laptop, both drives (connected to the hub) worked fine with no issues. Also, I did not use the hubs power supply at the time. So all the power came from my laptop.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - I don't understand your comment.  If they work fine what exactly is the problem?  There is only so much total power over a single hub, your laptop only has one, you can add 100 externally powered hubs and you would still be limited by the power of that single hub...

Comment: @Ramhound - I would like to know how much volts and amps does a typical USB port on a laptop supply to devices, either usb 2.0 or 3.0 port.

Comment: Just because it seems to work does not mean it is correct, you may be damaging your Laptop and/or RPi.

Comment: Yes, in the question it says I am trying to use this hub with a raspberry pie. Which cannot power this hub on its own

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi - There is a huge different between USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 power.  Pick one.  RasPi is a USB 2.0 only device.  So why are you asking about USB 3.0?

Comment: Since it worked with my laptop on both its usb 2 and 3 ports, I wanted to find a power supply that gives the same output as the usb ports on my laptop to the hub so that I would work with my raspberry pi.

Comment: Also I've read on my lapop's manufacture website that due to the nature of my laptop's motherboard, if it detects too much power going going to the usbs it would just cut off the power going there without affecting anything else, so that means the hub is working fine on my laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a parallel circuit, the voltage across each of the components is the same, and the total current is the sum of the currents through each component.
>   — [Series and parallel circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits)

So, you will need a charger that has **the same voltage** and **sums up the currents (ampere)**. You can provide more current than the calculated sum, as the attached devices will only consume the current they need. However, DO NOT provide less current than the sum or you could damage the charger and possibly its environment.